# Tkinter import with PyCharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I want to create a tkinter window using pycharm:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

Apparently PyCharm tells me that `from tkinter import *` is an unused import statement, and `root = Tk()` is an unresolved reference. What's confusing me is that the code works completely fine, a tkinter window shows up, no errors.

How do I fix this?

**Edit:** PyCharm shows these error whenever I import any other library I have.

Comment: try `import tkinter as tk` and `root = tk.Tk()`

Comment: But I believe you can manage it.

Comment: Stil gives me an error: "Cannot find reference Tk in imported module Tkinter". Again, the code works fine.

Comment: What version of Python and PyCharm are you using?

Comment: Python 3.5.2 and PyCharm 2016.2.2

Comment: Weird. I had used it for a while, never seen something like this though. Let us know some info about versions.

Comment: I think it's because I activated the PyCharm version using a "Licence server". here's the [link](https://xn--90agrrk8e.xn--p1ai/pycharm-activate-key-3-4-5-2016/). I don't know if that's the problem or not.

Comment: I did some imports to various modules but it seems that PyCharm doesn't give me the location of the module that I want to import . Before this problem above occurred, it used to give me the locations of any imports I do, let's say I want to import "requests" module, as long as I type " import req" a small window pops up and gives me the location of  requests module "C:\python3\Lib\..." Now it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

```
from Tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

thislabel = Label(root, text = "This is an string.")

thislabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Use `Tkinter` not `tkinter`

Answer (score 1):

> from tkinter import*

works just fine. You just have to go to the next line and type something along the lines of

> tk = Tk()

or any tkinter code and it will recognize it and work just fine.

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="Click Me")
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Does that code above work?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

At my case, the file that I was writing had the name "tkinter.py", when I imported the module "tkinter" what PyCharm did was import the file that I was writing, of course the message error: "Cannot find reference Tk in imported module tkinter" appeared. Its a dumb error, but **check that you file not called same as module.** ;)

EDIT:
If you use **"from tkinter import** * **"** you must run it like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

- Note the uppercase "T" in "Tk".

If you use **"import tkinter as tk"** you must run it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

- Note the "tk" module (lowercase) before "Tk" (uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

maybe check if you installed python in a virtual environment, if so you need to work your project there too

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to fix this problem myself, here's what I did:

- Deleted the ".idea" file associated with the project.
- In PyCharm: **File >> Open >> "path to project" >> Ok** (reopen project)

Now it it looks as normal as it was before.

Comment: PyCharm has a known issue that happens if you have multiple defined virtual environments pointed at the same virtual environment. Not sure if that affected your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by doing the following

- Delete the  .idea file.
- Delete the `__py_cache__` file.

Answer (score 0):

in python2 it is

```
from Tkinter import *
```

and is python 3 it is

```
from tkinter import *
```

I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Python 3 is clarified by OPs comments as well as by the python tag (python tag without a further version refers to 3). And the `from tkinter import *` was already sateted by several other answers. May you clarify how your answer adds further information?

Answer (score -1):

I have found out!!
You are actually have to install tkintertoy to use tkinter in pycharm.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a proper solution. tkintertoy is a separate project based on tkinter.